# Use ExecuteScript with Python to write JSON to file

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I'm trying to access the GitHub API and write the contents to a FlowFile. I could either create the FlowFile in the Python script or use GenerateFlowFile and send it into the script, I'm not picky. The code I have so far for creating the JSON is as follows (using urllib to comply with Jython):

```
import urllib.request
import json

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json {}'.format('cat'),
    'Authorization': 'token TOKEN_TEXT'
}

page = 1
response_text = []

while page > 0:
    req = urllib.request.Request(url="GITHUB_API_URL".format(page),\
                                 data=None, headers=headers)
    
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as resp:
        data = json.loads(resp.read().decode("utf-8"))

    
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
        else:
            response_text.extend(data)
            page += 1
```

I have confirmed I get the JSON as desired, I really just need to write `response_text` to a FlowFile to pass onto the next processor in my flow. I've tried researching, but I can't seem to find any hard documentation on the ExecuteScript processor (if you know where I could find that, I'd appreciate that, as well).

Comment: Is this python 2?

Comment: No, python 3. I've read ExecuteScript only works with pure python libraries, so I tried to keep it to just json and urllib

Comment: Consider the ExecuteStreamCommand process so that you can use standard Python instead of Jython. You can pass command-line options and set ENV variables. Set PYTHONPATH to find modules. This command replaces the flowfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a series of articles called the ExecuteScript Cookbook ([part 1](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922), [part 2](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-2/ta-p/249018) and [part 3](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-3/ta-p/249148)) that has (among other supported languages) Jython examples of common NiFi API calls. Take a look at Part 2 which deals with FlowFile I/O. I should mention that the Jython script engine used in NiFi is based on Python 2 not 3.